# How to send an individual email to multiple people using office.js

Tags: angularjs, office-js, outlook-web-addins

When sending mail from outlook using office.js, is there any feature to send mail individually?

For example, if you have 5 recipients, when you send an e-mail, the recipient can only see your own e-mail.

It has nothing to do with BCC.

Please let me know if that feature can be implemented in office.js.

Answer (score 0):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything out of the box. But I believe you can use EWS for creating and sending emails in the way you need. See [Creating and sending email messages by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633628(v=exchg.80)) for more information. The [makeEwsRequestAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#makeEwsRequestAsync_data__callback__userContext_) method can be helpful.

Another possible way is to use Graph API, see [Automate creating, sending, and processing messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-create-send-messages).

Comment: When sending mail from Outlook, it must be sent individually.

Comment: You can make use of Outlook On Send add-ins feature along with Graph/REST API to achieve this.
On Send add-ins Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows